# Не получается активировать Input в окне WebView2 C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет.
**Как активировать этот контрол / (нажать программно)?** Использую WebView2 в WinForm.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кликнуть на Input и начать вводить цифры, после 7й он сделает перенос на следующий контрол.

Я отправляю данные в форму так, но окно при этом остается "не активно" туда надо нажать еще

```
var focus = $"document.getElementById('field1').focus()";
var field = $"document.execCommand('insertText', true, '{numbers}')";

webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(focus);
webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(field);
```

на сайте это выглядит так:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
<input onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57" id="field1" type="tel" value="" pattern="[0-9]*">
</div>
```

> [Ссылка на сайт c этой формой](https://microsoft.gointeract.io/interact/index?interaction=1461173234028-3884f8602eccbe259104553afa8415434b4581-05d1&accountId=microsoft&loadFrom=CDN&appkey=196de13c-e946-4531-98f6-2719ec8405ce&Language=English&name=pana&CountryCode=en-US&Click%20To%20Call%20Caller%20Id=%2016265860337&startedFromSmsToken=e9dmQhQ&dnis=1&token=UEuUbt)

Уровень знаний ноль, но мне очень надо, спасибо кто решится направить или помоч

Comment: `document.getElementById('field1').value = ...` пробовали? Задизабленый можно включить например удалив у него атрибут `disabled=""`, но вы его не показали, точно сложно сказать. А с телефона мне сейчас не посмотреть.

Comment: @aepot `value = ...` увы не будет работать. Данный Input после каждого нажатия проверяет данные на условия (цифры 1-9, количество в поле), мы же просто присваиваем значение, и пока не кликнем в поле и не нажмем `{ENTER}` или `{RIGHT}` например, ничего не произойдет. Пока что я решил это так: `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}" + "{TAB}")` - что активирует нужное поле. Но мне бы конечно хотелось понять как это сделать посредством запроса

Comment: Работайте с запросами, а не с интерфейсом. Вот допустим SO, вы хотите сделать приложение, которое отправит комментарий, что, будете браузер брать для этого? Будете парсить HTML, отправлять команды кликов и прочее? А что мешает взять, нажать F12, отправить комментарий и посмотреть какой запрос и куда идет? Увидите там, что идет простой JSON на конкретный адрес, с конкретными данными. И вот уже мы понимаем, что UI нам как бы и не нужен, нам нужны лишь данные для запрсоа. Вот также и у вас, зачем целый браузер я не пойму, отсылать клики и прочее, если нужен лишь 1 запрос...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я понимаю что есть более адекватные решения, но их реализация слишком сложна для человека который никогда не занимался этим. Недавно я пробовал через Scrapy получать JSON с WB.RU и там мне это удавалось. На сейте указанном в данном посте при попытке открыть адрес запроса из заголовка XHR я получаю `{"code":"0x7000400","message":"Request is unauthorized, missing or wrong credentials","moreInfoUrl":"https://www.jacada.com/support"}` Не смог разобраться и решил пойти простым путем для начала тк у меня есть всего пару дней на готовое решение, где это лишь часть

Comment: Хах, для меня наоборот, использовать полноценный браузер, ковыряться в HTML и так далее, это более сложный путь, чем отправить один POST запрос) Не, я вас не заставляю, делайте как знаете. Я лишь говорю, что вы едите в магазин через дорогу на танке, что не очень целесообразно как по мне. Касательно ошибки - вам прямым текстом пишет "запрос не авторизован", то есть вы забыли отправить Cookie или Header с нужным ключем, который генерирует вам сайт при авторизации или первом заходе.